Integral (convolution) equation with singular kernel
I have stumbled upon an integral equation whose kernel involves a quotient of Gamma functions:
$$ x(2-x)f(x)+g(x)=-\int_{0}^{x}dy\;f(y)\;g(x-y), $$
where
$$g(x)=\frac{\Gamma(1-x)}{(1+x)\Gamma(x)}.$$
Instead of solving the equation, I need to answer two questions:

Will the solution, f(x), inherit the location of g's singularities? That is, will f have singularities only at the positive integers?

Will f's singularities be poles and logarithmic branch cuts, or do we expect f to have other types of singularites such as $$\frac{\text{Log}(1-\frac{u}{k})}{(k-u)^{\alpha}}?$$


My numerical analyisis seems to indicate that, indeed, f has singularities only at the positive integers in the form of poles and log branch cuts. However, I would like to know if there is any way to prove these statements rigorously.
P.S.  I welcome any bibliographical suggestions that may help to better understand the subject at hand.
